# How to setting using unicode font in Enterprise Architect

Tags: unicode, enterprise-architect, system-design, system-analysis

I try to draw Data Flow Diagram (DFD) by Enteprise Architect (EA). I am using Vietnamese, but Enterprise Architect only display true unicode at first time, then display error. If you using EA, let's try some unicode text: `"Sinh viên"`, `"Quản trị hệ thống`", `"Kho đồ án"` etc.. and figure out how to type unicode font and display, print these text true.

[image]

Thank you!

(I have been read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931928/how-to-use-unicode-in-enterprise-architect-9) , but answer doesn't figure out real solution, although the answer maked accepted)

Answer (score 3):

I use EA 10.x, your text is ok for storing in EA.
But, before add unicode symbols to your model you should perform following:

1. Switch on Jet4 support
2. Download empty jet4 project template from sparx
3. Import existing project to new one

or in details follow this instruction: http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/projects_and_teams/check_in_languages_other_than_.html